# how to set column value before persist in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

Suppose I have to set column value formula to 1. So how can I do it before persisting. After persisting I should get 1 in database.

```
 $f=1;
 $product->setFormula($f);
 $em->persist($product);
```

If I use above line it gives an error

> Expected value of type "Nimo\MrmdBundle\Entity\Product" for
>   association field "Nimo\MrmdBundle\Entity\Product#$basedOn", got
>   "integer" instead

Here is entity code

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="formula", referencedColumnName="someothercolumn",nullable=true)
 **/
private $formula = null;
```

Comment: Show your entity class.

Comment: I have added entity code above

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30373523/4841794 You need to persist an entity of type `$formula` rather than persisting an integer.

Comment: I dont have entity of type formula

Comment: Then what are you referencing it to? What is  `someothercolumn` ?

Comment: Also why do you have ManyToOne and Join Column?

Comment: Actually after submitting form I want to set the column of an entity (which is getting form details) to some diff value

Comment: We use setter method to redefine the column value right? how do we use it?

Comment: You're not answering my question. If your `$formula` is just a regular field in your entity (not a foreign key) then your entity is not defined correctly. Until you don't clarify that I'm not going to be able to help you. So is `$formula` a foreign key referencing another table? or its just a regular field of a table?

Comment: $formula column referring to another table's column

Comment: Then you have to persist it as an entity. There's no other way. See the link in my previous comments. That's the only way to go. you have to do a `findOneByID` and then persist that entity itself.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so mark the answer as corrected or share what solution did you come up with so that it helps other future users.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your **entity definition** first, However here's what you need to do in your controller. This will *not* work until you make sure your entities are correctly defined. (I can't because I don't know your entity definitions)

```
$f=1;
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Formula'); //This should be your referred entity
//You can also do findOneByName below
$formula= $repo->findOneById($id); //This should be the primary key of the referred entity NOT 1
$formula->setFormula($f);
$em->persist($formula);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a relationship between two entities you can not pass a single value or variable containing a single value.

Entity works on objects. So try to pass the object of some entity or create an object with some value it will work. I also face the same error while passing a single value. Just pass the Object of an entity relationship annotation will picked up the joining column of other entity.